# Unlock scaled print size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, scaling

When printing with Photoshop a set of options are available under "Scaled Print Size".

It allows you to change the Scale percentage. However I see a chain icon that symbolizes that the aspect ratio is locked, and I would like to scale the height and width independently.

I disabled "Scale to Fit Media" as was suggested, but the height and width are still locked.

Comment: Please disable "Scaling to Fit Media" first.

Comment: What version of photoshop are you using